Prove that $n \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left[\cos\left(\frac{\xi}{nx}\right)-1\right]f(x)\,dx \to-c|\xi|$
Problem. Suppose that $f(x)$ is a continuous density of some random variable and support on $[-1,1]$, that is, $f(x)\ge0$ and $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\,dx =1$.
If in addition, $f(0)>0$ , I want to show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left[ \cos\left(\frac{\xi}{nx}\right) - 1 \right] f(x) \, dx = -c|\xi|
$$
for some $c>0$.

My attempt:
I have proven that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left[ \cos\left(\frac{\xi}{nx}\right) - 1 \right] f(x) \, dx
= \lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \left[-2\sin\left(\frac{\xi}{2nx}\right)\right]f(x) \, dx $$
for any $0<\delta<1$, but I don't know how to continue, any comments will be appreciated.

The following standard machinery comes handy:

Lemma. (Approximation-to-the-identity) Assume that $K_n : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of integrable functions such that

$\int_{-1}^{1} K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \to C$ as $n \to \infty$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$,
$\sup_{n\geq 1} \int_{-1}^{1} |K_n(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x < \infty$, and
$\int_{-1}^{1} |K_n(x)| \mathbf{1}_{\{|x| > \delta\}} \, \mathrm{d}x \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for any $\delta > 0$.

Then, for any bounded measurable function $f : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous at $0$, we have
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-1}^{1} K_n(x) f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = Cf(0). $$

In OP's case, let $K_n$ be the function on $[-1, 1]$ defined by
$$ K_n(x) = n \left[ \cos\left(\frac{\xi}{nx}\right) - 1 \right] . $$
(We may set $K_n(0) = 0$ if we like, although the value of $K_n(0)$ does not affect the argument.) We claim that $K_n$ satisfies the assumptions of the lemma with $C = -\pi |\xi|$. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1} |K_n(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x
&= -\int_{-1}^{1} K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2n \int_{0}^{1} \left[ 1 - \cos\left(\frac{\xi}{nx}\right) \right] \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2|\xi| \int_{\frac{|\xi|}{n}}^{\infty} \frac{1 - \cos u}{u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u. \tag{$u = |\xi|/nx$}
\end{align*}
As $n \to \infty$, this integral monotone-increases to
$$ 2|\xi| \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - \cos u}{u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u = \pi |\xi|. $$
(This can be easily proved by integration by parts, together with $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin u}{u} \, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{\pi}{2} $.) This establishes Item 1 and 2 with $C = -\pi |\xi|$. Moreover, by a similar computation,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1} |K_n(x)|\mathbf{1}_{\{|x|>\delta\}} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= 2|\xi| \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - \cos u}{u^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{\frac{|\xi|}{n} < |u| < \frac{|\xi|}{n\delta}\}} \, \mathrm{d}u,
\end{align*}
which clearly converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ by the dominated convergence theorem. Therefore Item 3 is also established.
The upshot of these computations is that, for $f$ as in OP's setting,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left[ \cos\left(\frac{\xi}{nx}\right) - 1 \right] f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = -\pi |\xi| f(0). $$

Proof of Lemma. Let
$$
M = \sup_{x\in[-1,1]} |f(x)|
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
A = \sup_{n\geq 1} \int_{-1}^{1} |K_n(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
Also, fix $\delta > 0$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\left| \int_{-1}^{1} K_n(x)f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - Cf(0) \right|
&\leq \int_{-1}^{1} |K_n(x)|\cdot \left| f(x) - f(0)\right| \mathbf{1}_{\{|x|\leq \delta \}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\quad + \int_{-1}^{1} |K_n(x)|\cdot \left| f(x) - f(0)\right| \mathbf{1}_{\{|x| > \delta \}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\quad + |f(0)| \left|\int_{-1}^{1} K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - C \right| \\
&\leq A \left( \sup_{x \in [-\delta, \delta]} \left| f(x) - f(0)\right| \right) \\
&\quad + 2M \int_{-1}^{1} |K_n(x)| \mathbf{1}_{\{|x| > \delta \}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\quad + |f(0)| \left|\int_{-1}^{1} K_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - C \right|.
\end{align*}
$$
Taking $\limsup$ as $n\to\infty$, we obtain
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \int_{-1}^{1} K_n(x)f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - Cf(0) \right|
\leq A \left( \sup_{x \in [-\delta, \delta]} \left| f(x) - f(0)\right| \right). $$
Since the left-hand side does not depend on $\delta > 0$, letting $\delta \to 0^+$ shows that the $\limsup$ vanishes, proving the desired claim.

The excellent answer！Thank you so much
